# Total ink coverage on CMYK digital printing

Tags: software-recommendation, cmyk, digital-printing

Is there a simple way to calculate ink coverage when printing from *.pdf ?

I work at a digital printing studio and just got a new machine. 
With the machine came some cost tables which provides info about prices with 20,40,60 ... % coverage of paper.

When using CMYK palette, there is the possibility that ink coverage goes up to 400% (100% of C,M,Y,K) so I am looking for some fast and reliable way of getting to know how much ink is used before printing so I can modify prices. It should work with selected area or whole document.

Comment: Have you looked at [APFill?](http://avpsoft.com/products/apfill/) I haven't used it, but it looks like it does what you're asking.

Comment: The 400% has nothing to do with the total ink coverage. That is the Maximum ink on a rich black, and should be defined by the profile.

Answer (score 4):

Adobe Acrobat has a number of tools to analyze PDF documents.

You can use the Preflight tool (**Edit → Preflight...**) to analyze for any pre-print issues, including ink coverage, image resolution etc. and correct some issues. There are a number of preset profiles that you can use, I believe some contain ink coverage checks. You can create your own custom profiles and add your own checks, including ink coverage.

[image: Preflight custom checks]

You can read more about the Preflight tool here:

- [**Acrobat Help / Analyzing documents with the Preflight tool**](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/analyzing-documents-preflight-tool-acrobat.html)

If you just want to see the values you can use the Output Preview (**Tool → Print Production → Output Preview**). Set the preview to "Seperations" and you can hover over your pdf with your cursor and get live values for all inks and total coverage. You can also set a color to highlight any areas over a threshold of total coverage.

[image: Output preview]

*Note, this is using Acrobat Pro CS6, the newer Acrobat Pro DC (CC) may differ.*

Comment: This is a good answer about "total ink/total area coverage", but that just tells us how much ink there is in  a single spot. I think the OP needs to know how much ink there is going to be used in total when printing.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use [APFill Ink Coverage calculator](http://avpsoft.com/products/apfill/). It calculates coverage of the PDF file and you will get results like on screenshots. It shows separated coverage % for each of CMYK spots and up to 8 pantone colors for each page of the PDF file.

[image: APFill Ink Coverage Calculator CMYK results]
[image]

Comment: It's a nice software, however, there's available a similar freeware sw? The algorythm should be pretty easy to remake, even a python or php class could work...